# How to compile paython package in c++ work space

Tags: c++

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi ,

I want to use paython package in c++ workspace as package available in paython not in c++ . Could you let me know the approach for the same . Is it advisable to use paython package in c++ workspace ?
I don't have any experience in paython but want to use paython package so that information can be published through topics .

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/256546/how-to-compile-paython-package-in-c++-work-space/) by [can-43811](https://answers.ros.org/users/29359/can-43811/) on ROS Answers with karma: 101 on 2017-03-08

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure what you mean by a C++ workspace, but you are free to mix and match different languages within the same package and workspace. Nodes written in different languages can communicate via topics and services (for the most part, I haven't yet encountered any limitations/problems). In fact, I do this all the time. I'll often write some nodes in Python and some in C++ and there's never an issue.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2017-03-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [can-43811](https://answers.ros.org/users/29359/can-43811/) on 2017-03-26**:
catkin make is different for python and c++. I do require some packages in python and c++ as well by making sure that both are compiled on similar and integrated  build environment,

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-03-26**:
`catkin_make` will only compile C++, in fact, you don't compile Python at all. You can use packages built with Python and packages built with C++ in the same workspace without any problems, except in very rare circumstances. You can also use Python and C++ in the same package.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2018-01-17**:
@can-43811 if this answered your question, please click on the check mark to mark the answer as correct.